# Vue.3 does not render Vuetify components when using at tag attribute in transition-group

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js, gsap

I want to animate some cards using gsap for the following components in Vue.js 3.

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import gsap from 'gsap'
import { useTranslate } from '@/@core/composable/useTranslate'
import TimeLineItem from './TimeLineItem.vue'

interface ITimeLine {
  icon: string
  title: string
  description: string
  color: string
}
const timeLines = ref<ITimeLine[]>([
  {
    title: 'PadvishInstall',
    description: 'timeline-welcome',
    icon: 'material-symbols:looks-one-outline',
    color: 'warning',
  },
  {
    title: 'InsertingToken',
    description: 'timeline-step1',
    icon: 'ic:outline-looks-two',
    color: 'error',
  },
  {
    title: 'ContactInfo',
    description: 'timeline-step2',
    icon: 'ph:number-square-three-bold',
    color: 'info',
  },
])

const { translate } = useTranslate()

/**
 * Functions
 */

const beforeEnter = (el: Element) => {
  const he = el as HTMLElement

  he.style.opacity = '0'
  he.style.transform = 'translateX(100px)'
}

const enter = (el: Element, done: () => void) => {
  const he = el as HTMLElement

  gsap.to(el, {
    opacity: 1,
    x: 0,
    duration: 0.8,
    onComplete: done,
    delay: Number((el as HTMLElement).dataset.index) * 0.5,
  })
}
</script>

<template>
  <VCard class="text-center" variant="text" title="card title">
    <VCardText>
      <transition-group
        align="start"
        justify="center"
        truncate-line="both"
        :density="$vuetify.display.smAndDown ? 'compact' : 'default'"
        appears
        @before-enter="beforeEnter"
        @enter="enter"
        tag="v-timeline"
      >
        <TimeLineItem
          v-for="(item, index) in timeLines"
          :key="index"
          :data-index="index"
          :title="translate(item.title)"
          :description="translate(item.description)"
          :icon="item.icon"
          :color="item.color"
        />
      </transition-group>
     
    </VCardText>
  </VCard>
</template>
```

TimeLineItem component :

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
interface Props {
  icon: string
  title: string
  description: string
  color: string
}

const props = defineProps<Props>()
</script>

<template>
  <VTimelineItem size="x-small" fill-dot>
    <template #icon>
      <div class="v-timeline-avatar-wrapper rounded-circle">
        <VAvatar size="small">
          <VIcon size="100" :icon="icon" :color="color" />
        </VAvatar>
      </div>
    </template>
    <VCard>
      <VCardText>
        <!--  Header -->
        <div class="d-flex justify-space-between">
          <h6 class="text-base font-weight-semibold mb-1 me-3">
            {{ title }}
          </h6>
        </div>

        <!--  Content -->
        <p class="mb-1">
          {{ description }}
        </p>
      </VCardText>
    </VCard>
  </VTimelineItem>
</template>
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.v-timeline-avatar-wrapper {
  background-color: rgb(var(--v-theme-background));
}
</style>
```

For animating each element of `v-timeline`, I used `transition-group` and set the value of tag to `v-timeline`. But, when using `transition-group`, the Vue does not recognize the 'v-timeline' is a vuetify component and must render a component!.
This is a limitation of transition-group  or can be considered as a bug in Vue.3?